# Wrong CPM and revenue value Google AdManager Report API

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I am trying to pull report from google ad manager using API

```js
  report_job = {
  'reportQuery': {
      'dimensions': ['AD_EXCHANGE_DATE', 'AD_EXCHANGE_COUNTRY_NAME'],
      'columns': ['AD_EXCHANGE_AD_REQUESTS', 'AD_EXCHANGE_IMPRESSIONS',
                  'AD_EXCHANGE_ESTIMATED_REVENUE','AD_EXCHANGE_AD_ECPM'],
      'dateRangeType': 'LAST_WEEK',
      'timeZoneType': 'AD_EXCHANGE',  # Run in pacific time
      'adxReportCurrency': 'USD'
  }
  }
```

I suspect the downloaded report has very wired ECPM and Revenue values. as below

[image]

Please help if i am doing something wrong, as the ECPM has to be very low and the revenue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Money values are always specified in terms of micros which are a millionth of the fundamental currency unit. For US dollars, $1 is 1,000,000 micros."

From the AdManager API official documentation here: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202008/LineItemService.Money#microAmount